# How to safely allow current access to nested maps in go?

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, nested-map

I'm a bit confused about how to ensure I safe concurrent access to nested maps.
Originally my setup was like this, bit I realize I'd need to be able to lock at least one of the maps.

```
map[string]map[string]Dish
```

After some thought, the structures I am envisioning look like this:

```
type Manager struct {
    mu sync.RWMutex
    locations map[string]Restaurant
}
type Restaurant struct {
    mu sync.RWMutex
    menu map[string]Dish
}
type Dish struct {
    name string
    price string
    vegan bool
}
```

My basic understanding is as follows:
If I want to add a new `Restaurant` to `locations`, I'd need to lock `Manager`.
If I wanted to add or modify a `Dish` to `menu`, I'd need to lock `Restaurant`, but I'm not sure if I'd need to lock the `Manager` as well. 
Similarly, if I wanted to access values from `Manager`, I'm not sure if I'd need to lock `Restaurant` as well.

I've tried (unsuccessfully) to force data races while using the `-race` flag, so I'm not sure if locking `Manager` anytime `Restaurant` is mutated, and locking `Restaurant` everytime I access `Manager` is necessary, or if my attempts to force a race didn't work.

Comment: Should not mutex to be pointer to work properly? U better add code to show how to you are locking and to ensure your are not locking different mutexes

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28244472/1286423
You should use a pointer to mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want to be copying locks, so you need to use pointers:

```
type Manager struct {
    mu sync.RWMutex
    locations map[string]*Restaurant
}
type Restaurant struct {
    mu sync.RWMutex
    menu map[string]Dish
}
```

Once you have a `*Restaurant` instance, you have to lock it to write to `menu`, and rlock it to read from `menu`.

To get a restaurant by map lookup, you need to rlock the `Manager`, and to add things to the `Manager`, you need to lock it.

So if you want to start from the top and go to the bottom, you have to lock both the manager and then the restaurant. You also have to make sure you lock them in the same order (manager first, restaurant next) whenever you do this to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Thank you, great point about the pointer. I was still in the mindset that "a map is a pointer" but Restaurant is a struct not a map.
This answers my questions very succinctly, thank you very much!

Comment: @jimpeter you might also look at [`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) but be sure you have read the caveats carefully. (Still, it's perfectly OK you implemented it yourself.)